# Update SQL Server table using a gridview aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a stored procedure that grabs a table and manipulates it to grab only certain records. This is working fine. I'm confused how I can write a stored procedure just to update the records using the edit feature on the gridview. And where to place this stored procedure on my aspx page?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspPackingShiftTargetGetData] 
    @ProductShortDesc VARCHAR(16)
AS
    SELECT 
        ProductPackingShiftTarget.id, 
        ProductPackingShiftTarget.ShiftHour,    
        ProductPackingShiftTarget.ProductShortDescription, 
        ItemFrameSizeMaster.Description,
        ProductPackingShiftTarget.Quantity,  
        ProductPackingShiftTarget.FrameSizeMasterId
    FROM 
        ProductPackingShiftTarget 
    RIGHT JOIN 
        ItemFrameSizeMaster ON ProductPackingShiftTarget.FrameSizeMasterId = ItemFrameSizeMaster.id
    WHERE 
        ProductShortDescription = @ProductShortDesc

--EXEC dbo.uspPackingShiftTargetGetData @ProductShortDesc = 'g120c'
```

Ok so this returns the items in the table I want, but now I need a stored procedure that updates just the quantity column based on the `Id` column.

And not sure how to implement this in my aspx page if anybody can help?

Comment: Please put some of the sample code that you have did. Here we can help to resolve your error.

Comment: You can try `SqlDataSource` with `SelectCommand` and `UpdateCommand` so that when editing has done the update query will execute and rebind updated data. To bind the SP result into a `GridView`, use `DataBind()` in code-behind.

Comment: Thanks.. i have tryed update paramter now its saying i have too many arguments...  
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="@Target" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="@Id"/>
              </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>